# How can I pause all jQuery animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm going to have cases where I need to pause all the animations on the page in order to do some user interaction, and then resume all the animations as soon as the user has responded.

For example, I might have an animation that's fading in over a 1s period, and 400ms in I need to pause it. It should stop at 40% opacity, and stay there until I resume, at which point it should pick up where it left off and spend another 600ms completing its fade-in from 40% to 100%.

There might be multiple animations on the page simultaneously, and I want to pause them all. Additionally, some animations might have further animations queued to continue after they complete, and that all needs to work: when I resume, the current animation needs to finish, and then the next one in the queue needs to start, just as if nothing happened.

jQuery doesn't seem to have any built-in support for pausing animations; the closest I can find is [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which will stop at the current spot in the animation, but can't resume later; and it either moves on to the next animation in the queue immediately, or clears the animation queue entirely.

How can I pause the animations in a way that will let me resume them later?

Comment: Never tried it but maybe this is working: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pause / Resume Option**

The [pause plugin](http://tobia.github.com/Pause/) will work well for this situation.

**HTML**

```
<div class=demo>
    <div id="box1" class="animationToPause"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="animationToPause"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="animationToPause"></div>
</div>
<input id="btnPause" type="button" value="Pause Animations" />
```

**CSS**

```
div.demo {
    border: 1px solid #555;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 550px;
}
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#box1 {
    background: #0C0;
}
#box2 {
    background: #090;
}
#box3 {
    background: #060;
}​
```

**​JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    //Begin animation on boxes
    $("div[id^='box']").each(function() {
        phase1($(this));
    });

    //Setup animation pause/resume on hover
    $("div[id^='box']").hover(function() {
        $(this).pause();
    }, function() {
        $(this).resume();
    });
});

//Toggle animation pause/resume on button click
$("#btnPause").toggle(
    function() {
        $(".animationToPause").pause();
    }, function() {
        $(".animationToPause").resume()
});

//Animation 1
function phase1($this) {
    $this.animate({
        left: 450
    }, 2000, 'swing', function() {
        phase2($this)
    });
}

//Animation 2
function phase2($this) {
    $this.animate({
        left: 0
    }, 2000, 'swing', function() {
        phase1($this)
    });
}​
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/yNE53/).

**Brute Force Option**

Certainly not what you're looking for, but related.

Setting [`jQuery.fx.off = true;`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) will stop all animations immediately.

Comment: With that update, I can finally upvote your answer. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @JimmyX, lol. I think *finally* may be a bit too strong a word. I added the additional option about 30 seconds after the first :P

Comment: This plugin doesn't quite get it right with respect to the easing function (it restarts the easing at the beginning when you resume, so if you had something like [easeInBack](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) then you'd get the initial bounce-out again after you resume). But it does get the timing right and keeps the queue intact, which are the important parts; the easing I think I can live with. Thanks!